# Can I call two separate iterations of pthread_create?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

My question pertains to some code I am currently working on. It involves the use of pthreads to read the line count in a group of files and print each individual line number and the total line count of each file. I am currently hitting a wall in reference to how to do the second portion of this as I was told that my main function cannot tally the totals, but only print them.

This is my code, I am also *very new* to pthreads so if there are basic mistakes I just didn't notice them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct thread_data {
    char *thread_id;
    int count;
    int total;
};

static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

///This is the individual file counter
void *filecount(void *thread_arg){
    struct thread_data *arg = thread_arg;

    FILE *fp = fopen(arg->thread_id, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s\n", arg->thread_id);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    for (int c = getc(fp); c != EOF || c == EOF; c = getc(fp)){
        if (c == '\n') {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            arg->count++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
        if (c == EOF){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            arg->count++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    return NULL;
}
///This is the total line counter amoungst all the files
void *counter(void *thread_array){
    struct thread_data *array = thread_array;

    for (int i = 0; i < array->count; i++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        array->total += array[i].count;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc == 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    argv++;
    argc--;

    ///Initializer
    pthread_t threads[argc];
    struct thread_data thread_data_array[argc];
    thread_data_array->count = argc;
    thread_data_array->total = 0;

    ///Thread Initializer
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        thread_data_array[i].thread_id = argv[i];
        thread_data_array[i].count = 0;
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, filecount, (void *) &thread_data_array[i]);
    }

    ///Thread Individual Printer
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        printf("File name: %4s - Line Count: %d \n", thread_data_array[i].thread_id, thread_data_array[i].count);
    }

    ///Thread Total(er)
    pthread_create((pthread_t *) &threads, NULL, counter, (void *) &thread_data_array);
    pthread_join((pthread_t) &threads, NULL);
    printf("Total line count: %d\n", thread_data_array->total);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _" I was told that my main function cannot tally the totals, but only print them"_ - So, is your question about how to (safely) collect the results in one thread? By just skimming through your code, it looks like that's what your aim is. `c != EOF || c == EOF` looks like a logic flaw though. That can be replaced with `true`, right? Try out the logic for one thread only. If that works, think about how to make it work for multiple threads - don't do it the other way around.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have made that change for the EOF part of the for loop and I am currently changing the file count function to take in the entire array and do everything in that function. I don't know if this is totally possible but I want to test to see if it is. If it works I'll post it here for folks to critique.

Comment: Almost anything is possible. Just be clear in your description about what your goal is and someone can probably help out if you have problems. If you have working code, this is not the place to post it to get critique though. There's a site called https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ that is better suited for that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I never knew that thank you for the help.

Comment: It's unclear how the title question is related to the code and prose in the question body.  It is also *generally* unclear what you're actually asking.  "Please help me write / fix my code" is not a question we ordinarily answer here. At least, not in those or similar terms.